# Deployment of a spring-boot app generates error "UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type"

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, service-locator, zipexception

So I am trying to deploy a Spring boot app (.jar file) that uses LiquiBase 3.5.3. I keep running into the following error :

27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR    Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.setResourceAccessor(ServiceLocator.java:107)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.(ServiceLocator.java:44)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.(ServiceLocator.java:31)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            ... 21 more
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:470)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:404)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:438)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:388)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:219)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at java.util.jar.Manifest.(Manifest.java:73)
27/03/18 12:52:19.538 [APP/20-0] ERR            at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.setResourceAccessor(ServiceLocator.java:97)

Please advise a workaround, this is really a blocker.
Thanks a lot.